# How to create a discord.py channel in a specific category?

Tags: python, discord.py

```
ticket_number = int(data["ticket-counter"])
ticket_number += 1

ticket_channel = await ctx.guild.create_text_channel("ticket-{}".format(ticket_number))
await ticket_channel.set_permissions(ctx.guild.get_role(ctx.guild.id), send_messages=False, read_messages=False)
```

Can someone guide with the example code, assuming the fact that the channel is created in a category.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to get the category where you want the channel to be

```py
# By name
category = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.categories, name="some name")
# By ID (you can also use `Guild.get_channel`
category = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.categories, id=123123)
```

You can now pass it when creating the channel as a kwarg

```py
ticket_channel = await ctx.guild.create_text_channel("...", category=category)
```

You can also create a channel within the category object itself

```py
ticket_channel = await category.create_text_channel("...")
```

#### Reference:

- [`CategoryChannel.create_text_channel`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.CategoryChannel.create_text_channel)